# daysBetween >= 23 HOURS means 1 more day and < 23 HOURS = the same day?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, days

What is the rule to calculate daysBetween ??
Try a simple apex code and find something strange.
When two days are compare, if 23hours between them they are 1 day between. Why not 24 hours ?
The test code:

```
Datetime dt,dt0,dt1;
dt = Date.Today();
dt0 = dt.addHours(23);
dt0 = dt0.addMinutes(-1);
dt1 = dt.addHours(23);
dt1 = dt1.addMinutes(0);

Date d,d0,d1;
d=Date.ValueOf(dt);
d0=Date.ValueOf(dt0);
d1=Date.ValueOf(dt1);

System.debug(dt);
System.debug(d0+'|'+d.daysBetween(d0)); // 0
System.debug(d1+'|'+d.daysBetween(d1)); // 1
```

Comment: Hi @SF, there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there! :)